# Constant X is not a type name, here x is KING

Tags: c++, oop, enums

I am getting an error over the argument of KING and COLOR that i passed to the Piece constructor. This is my code i am makinga  chess game with a class main then tehre is a game class which makes a board object, board plays the game and has squares and pieces as component objects. They both are heaving an association relationship

```
 /////////////////////////PIECE HEADER///////////////////
enum PIECETYPE { KING, QUEEN, ROOK, BISHOP, KNIGHT, PAWN };
enum COLOR { BLACK, WHITE };
class Square;//forward declaration

class Piece
{
    PIECETYPE type;
    COLOR color;
    ...};
/////////////////////PIECE CPP////////////////////////

#include "Piece.h"
#include"Square.h"



Piece::Piece()
{
}
Piece::Piece(PIECETYPE typ, COLOR clr){
    type = typ;
    color = clr;
    pSquare = nullptr;
}
//////////////////////BOARD HEADER: COMPOUNDCLASS////////////////////////
#include"Piece.h"``


class Board
{
    Square square[8][8];
    Piece wK(KING, WHITE);
    Piece bK(KING, BLACK);};
```

Comment: To the compiler those look like function declarations. You can have Piece members, but you'll need to initialize them in your constructor.

Comment: simply using brace-construction in the declaration works: `Piece wK{KING, WHITE};`

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version?

Comment: I am using VS 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use that constructor syntax when declaring the member variable of a class. The compiler does not know if you are trying to declare a member function with name `wK` and return type `Piece`, in which case `KING` should be the type of the first argument.

```
class Board {
    Piece wK(KING, WHITE);  // ERROR: this is declaring wK and using its constructor in ambigous way.
    ...
};
```

This is the way to do it:

```
class Board {
    Piece wK;  // declaring the member wK
    Board() : wk(KING, WHITE) {}  // initialize wK in the Board constructor
    ...
};
```

Alternatively, in C++11

```
class Board {
    Piece wK{KING, WHITE};  // Using {} instead of () makes it clear you are not declaring a function
    ...
};
```

Comment: There's no need to do this since 2011. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization

Answer (score 0):

In your Board class, create a collection of pieces like you did for the Squares. See the CreatePieces() method below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

enum PIECETYPE { KING, QUEEN, ROOK, BISHOP, KNIGHT, PAWN };
enum COLOR { BLACK, WHITE };
enum RANK { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H };

class Square
{
public:
    explicit Square() { }

private:
    //COLOR color;
    //RANK rank;
    //int file;
};

class Piece
{
public:
    explicit Piece(PIECETYPE typ, COLOR clr) : type(typ), color(clr) { }

private:
    PIECETYPE type;
    COLOR color;
    Square* pSquare{ nullptr };
};

class Board
{
public:
    explicit Board()
    {
        CreatePieces();
        // Set the pieces in their proper location, etc.
    }

private:
    Square squares[8][8];
    vector<Piece> pieces;

    inline void CreatePieces()
    {
        pieces.emplace_back(Piece(KING, WHITE));
        pieces.emplace_back(Piece(KING, BLACK));
        // etc. for 30 other pieces
    }
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Board> board = make_unique<Board>();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: There is so much in your code i don't understand, first libraries memory and unordered maps, and then what is explicit, i am stuck. havent used curly braces ever

Comment: @RoshaanAhmed You can omit the explicit keyword if you like and not worry about it.  It's just a good practice that prevents constructors from making type conversion.  The memory library was included for the use of unique_ptr, but you don't need to use that if it is confusing you.  You are using curly braces too with your constructors.  Mine probably looks funny because that scope was left empty.  Unordered map include was not needed- that was left over from working on a different problem.  I'll remove that.

Comment: @n.m. There was no question asked.  The original poster complained of an error and my response shows a way to remove the error within the original context.

Comment: @Overbyte Your design change is only applicable in this narrow context. It won't help anyone to avoid similar errors in ever so slightly different contexts.